# Simplify dictionary (xcode keeps indexing forever)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I've encountered a bug, where xcode starts indexing my files forever, using all the processor time.
I googled this problem and managed to understand that the following code is causing this bug:

```
    private struct Database {

    let db = [
        "oasis" : [
            "id" : "oasis",
            "sector_id" : "oasis",
            "name" : "Oasis",
            "type" : "planet",
            "image" : "planet_oasis",
            "xPos" : 170,
            "yPos" : 10,
            "spaceport" : true
        ],
        "oasis_hub" : [
            "id" : "oasis_hub",
            "sector_id" : "oasis",
            "name" : "Oasis Hub",
            "type" : "station",
            "image" : "station_oasis_hub",
            "xPos" : 30,
            "yPos" : 70,
            "spaceport" : true
        ],
        "oasis_exit" : [
            "id" : "oasis_exit",
            "sector_id" : "oasis",
            "name" : "Oasis sector exit",
            "type" : "exit",
            "image" : "planet_oasis",
            "xPos" : -350,
            "yPos" : 0,
            "spaceport" : false
        ]
    ]
}
```

I am trying to split this statement into several lines, but no luck so far. I keep getting "statement required" errors every time. Probably because I am doing something wrong since I am a total noob.

I've tried things like this:

```
var db: Array<Dictionary<String, NSObject>> = Array<Dictionary<String, NSObject>>()
db.append(["oasis" : ["name" : "oasis"]])
```

It worked in the playground, but failed to work in my project.
So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I had a compiler crash due to an internal struct. I made it global and my sorrow was gone.

Comment: To make you frown even more: I inserted that code in one of my sources and it compiled with no issue :-/

Comment: It compiles okay but then xcode starts to index my files again and again.

Comment: Oh, When I add `let db = Database()` things go loop...

Comment: Maybe if you’re storing structured data of heterogenous types, you want to think about a struct instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it:

```
    let db:[String:[String:AnyObject]] = [
```

will salvage the issue.