# Xcode shows indexing for new project for ever

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have several projects which i can open and run in xcode without any problem (indexing don't takes much time). When I create a new universal swift core data integrated project it shows indexing for ever, I don't know why this happens.? Restarted Mac, deleted xcode and installed new one. Still the same problem.

Also I created a new project in another xcode which is in another computer and opened it in this xocde (which has indexing problem), here this project also shows indexing for ever. I am using xcode 6.1 (Not beta) in MacMini

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
```

I found this a universal medicine to cure several XCode hick-ups.

Eventually you can try to kill SourceKitService in the activity monitor:
[image]

Select the process and click the x top left.

Comment: Same indexing problem even after trying this command. Sorry :(

Comment: I had this with the declaration of a dictionary which made it loop. Wait a minute...

Comment: But in this situation, i dont have anything. its a new project.

Comment: I meant this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727391/simplify-dictionary-xcode-keeps-indexing-forever/27727456#27727456 But if it's a new project then you should just kill SourceKitService.

Comment: How can i kill SourceKitService.?